# A hosted blog platform with anonymous posting?

Tags: blogging, privacy, hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is your favourite service for bloggers?](https://superuser.com/questions/8702/what-is-your-favourite-service-for-bloggers)

I'm launching a blog where anonymous users will need to make posts. What hosted blog platform allows anonymous users to publish posts with images?

Comment: I don't think SuperUser would be the best place to ask a question like that. ServerFault.com might be a better place, but it probably still wouldn't go down too well there either.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't a suitable question for Super User. From the FAQ (http://superuser.com/faq) - "Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about … and it is not about … websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and **WordPress** "

Comment: ChrisF is correct, but also check out linked question above.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do you mean anonymous, as in not disclosing their username to readers, or anonymous, as in not giving any details about themselves even to the blog platform? Or some other sort?

The first kind of anonymity is supported by most platforms. The system will know the username and details, but none of the readers will.

The second kind is a really complicated problem, if you stop to think about it. The thing is, everything you do online leaves a trace. Even an anonymous blogging platform will probably record the IP-address and timestamp associated with the post. And even if the blog platform woudn't by itself record any of the activity, traces of the posting activity would remain in the server logs of the platform. Any connection is also routed through multiple points in the internet, which can record the activity. Any of these traces can be used to compromize true anonymity. There are some internet anonymizers that might be used to do this, however, but each poster would then have to route any traffic related to posting through such a service.

Comment: @Ilari: I mean anonymously in the sense "Without the need to sign up for the service".

Comment: @Alex: Ah, ok! So it's more of an ease-of-use thing. You don't require "true" anonymity, but the writers shoudn't have to go through a registration process - makes sense. I suggest rewording the topic as *"... with possibility to post as unregistered user"* to be more specific.

I don't myself know of such service, but there might be one available. A good starting point is the Wikipedia list hosted blog services: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Blog_hosting_services